# Root of a polynomial $p(x)$ and asymptotic behaviour of the Taylor series of $\frac{1}{p(x)}$

Tags: polynomials, taylor-expansion, roots

I noticed that for a larger number of polynomials $p(x)$, it is possible to obtain the smallest positive real root by computing the Taylor series (more precisely the Maclaurin series) for $\frac{1}{p(x)}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kx^k$ as the limit of $\frac{a_k}{a_{k+1}}$ for $k$ going to infinity.

*Example:*

Take $p(x)=1-x-x^2-x^3-x^7$, then the Maclaurin series of $\frac{1}{p(x)}$ is given by
$$\frac{1}{p(x)}=1+x+2x^2+4x^3+\dots+227675342x^{32}+422234731x^{33}+\dots
$$
and
$$\frac{a_{32}}{a_{33}}=\frac{227675342}{422234731}=.5392150983... \, ,
$$
which is an excellent approximation to the smallest positive real root of $p(x)$.

I'm pretty sure that this fact is already known, but can't find any reference for it. Does somebody have any reference for it?
Thank you very much for any hint.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that this is not true in general? For instance, if $p(x)=x^3-2x^2+x-2$ then the smallest (indeed the only) real root is $2$, but the limit that you mention is $1$.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, that's why I wrote "for a larger number of polynomials", I do not know the necessary conditions, which is why I am looking for references.

Comment: A necessary condition is that the the root with the smallest absolute value is real (in my example, the roots with smallest absolute value are $\pm i$). I don't know a reference, but I can provide a proof. Just not right now.

Comment: That would already be quite a step forward, hope to read from you sometime later, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your conjecture is correct if the polynomial has a single root
of least absolute value (among all *complex* roots), i.e.

- $p(0) \ne 0$
- $z_1 \in \Bbb C$ is a root: $p(z_1) = 0$,
- All other roots $z_j \in \Bbb C$ satisfy $|z_j| > |z_1|$.

This is a special case of the following more general result:

> Let $f$ be holomorphic in some disk $B_R(0)$ with a single zero $z_1 \ne 0$
>   in $B_R(0)$, and let the Maclaurin series for $\frac 1f$ be
>   $$
>  \frac{1}{f(z)} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k z^k \, .
> $$
>   Then $a_k \ne 0$ for all sufficiently large $k$,  $(\frac{a_k}{a_{k+1}})_k$ is convergent and
>   $$
>  \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{a_k}{a_{k+1}} = z_1 \, .
> $$

*Remark:* The assumption that there is a *single* root of least
absolute value cannot be dropped, as $f(z) = 1-z^2$ or any even
function shows.

*Proof:* We can write $f(z) = \left(1 - \frac{z}{z_1} \right) g(z)$
where $g$ is holomorphic and non-zero in $B_R(0)$. The Maclaurin
series for $\frac 1g$
$$
  \frac{1}{g(z)} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k z^k
$$
converges for $|z| < R$. Then
$$
\frac{1}{f(z)} = \left( \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{z_1^k} \right)
\left( \sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k z^k \right) 
= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left( \sum_{l=0}^k \frac{b_l}{z_1^{k-l}}\right) z^k
$$
and therefore
$$
 a_k = \sum_{l=0}^k \frac{b_l}{z_1^{k-l}} = \frac{1}{z_1^k} \sum_{l=0}^k b_l z_1^l  
 = \frac{1}{z_1^k} \left( \frac{1}{g(z_1)} - \sum_{l=k+1}^\infty b_l z_1^l  \right) = \frac{1}{z_1^k} \left( \frac{1}{g(z_1)} - R_k \right)
$$
where
$$
 R_k = \sum_{l=k+1}^\infty b_l z_1^l 
$$
is the series remainder of the convergent series for $1/g(z_1)$,
and that converges to zero for $k \to \infty$.
It follows that $a_k \ne 0$ for all sufficiently large $k$, and
$$
 \frac{a_k}{a_{k+1}} = z_1 \frac{\frac{1}{g(z_1)} - R_k }{\frac{1}{g(z_1)} - R_{k+1} }
 \to z_1
$$
for $k \to \infty$.

Comment: I am not sure whether the conclusion in the last line is correct, I'll have to go through this in detail. Thank you nevertheless.

Comment: @R.J.Etienne: The Taylor series for $1/g(z_1)$ is convergent, therefore $\lim_{k \to \infty}  \sum_{l=k+1}^\infty b_l z_1^k = 0$. Let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: My fault, I read $z_l$ instead of $z_1$, sorry.

Comment: @R.J.Etienne: Note that (under the condition that there is a single root $z_1$ of least absolute value) this both proves that $a_k/a_{k+1}$ has a limit, and that the limit is equal to $z_1$. If there are 2 roots of equal absolute value then $a_k/a_{k+1}$ need not have a limit at all, for example $p(z) = 1 - z^2$, $1/p(z) = 1+z^2+z^4 + \ldots$ (or any even function).

Comment: You're absolutely right. Luckily, the polynomials I consider all have a single root of least absolute value.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that:

- $p(0)\neq0$;
- $p(x)$ has a real root $r$;
- for every root $\lambda$ of $p(x)$, $|\lambda|\geqslant|r|$.

Then a standard Complex Analysis theorem tells us that the radius of convergence of the Taylor series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ of $\frac1{p(x)}$ is $|r|$. This is equivalent to asserting that$$\limsup_{n\in\mathbb N}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=\frac1r.$$In a large amount of cases, this happens if and only if$$\lim_{n\in\mathbb N}\left|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\right|=r.$$

Comment: The Cauchy-Hadamard theorem, I should have thought of it myself! Thank you very much.

Comment: @R.J.Etienne I'm glad I could help.

Comment: But the conclusion $\limsup\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=\frac1r \Longrightarrow |\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}| \to r$ requires that the latter limit is *known* to exist.

Comment: @MartinR Which conclusion do you have in mind? All I wrote was that it happens in a large amount of cases.

Comment: How do you define “large amount of cases"?

Comment: @MartinR I don't. It's a common English expression, not a mathematical expression. How do you define “mind”. How do you define “conclusion”?

Answer (score 0):

*I do not know if this could help you.*

Considering that we want to solve $f(x)=0$, let us write $\frac 1{f(x)}$ as a $[1,n]$ Padé approximant around $x=0$
$$\frac 1{f(x)}=\frac{a^{(n)}_0+a^{(n)}_1 x}{1+\sum_{k=1}^n b_k x^k}$$ making the approximate solution to be $$x_{(n)}=-\frac{a^{(n)}_0 } {a^{(n)}_1 }=(n+1)\frac{ f^{(n)}(0)}{f^{(n+1)}(0)}$$

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, but this is not quite what I'm looking for.